# section tag display not working

Tags: html, css

Why is the section tag not not displaying my background color and border under the navigation tag? Could anyone help me with this. Been working around with this for a while now.

```css
nav{
    border:1px solid black;
    background-color:whitesmoke;
}

a:hover{
    color:black;
}

section{
    border:1px solid black;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>TheYomads</title>
    <!--Bootstrap-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="indexstyle.css">
  </head>
  <body class="container">
    <img src="images/yomadface.png" alt="yomadface.png" class="img-responsive">
    <nav>
      <a href="index.php">Home</a>
      <a href="blog.php">Blog</a>
      <a href="photography.php">Photography</a>
    </nav>
    <section>
     <h1>This is the place for your homepage.</h1>
    </section>          
    <footer>          
    </footer>    
  </body>    
</html>
```

Comment: I mean the whole section itself. It does not show the border from the css file.

Comment: You haven't set a background color for the section

Comment: `border:yellow;` is nullifying the `border:1px solid black;` rule. I also see no background color rule being set on the section element.

Comment: yeah ^ you need to used `border-color:yellow;`

Answer (score 3):

When you specify a shorthand property like `border`, any values you do not specify get a default value.

```
border: yellow
```

is equivalent to:

```
border: 0 none yellow
```

Either set `border-color: yellow` or `border: 1px solid yellow`.

Comment: I made the necessary change. Thanks for pointing that out. But it still dosen't render the yellow background color nor the border parameters.

Comment: @Goldensquare — It does in the live demo in your question

Comment: It is working in the live snippet and jsfiddle, but not in my local machine.

Comment: @Goldensquare — We can't tell what is different in the version we can't see.

Comment: @Goldensquare Check the console for errors. Also, is the code above the same as what you're running locally?

Comment: Indeed it is. I have now checked 5 times.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a stab at this and assume that you wanted the `background-color` of your `section` to be yellow with the border you defined. It seems that you may have missed your CSS attribute.

Rather than having two `border` attributes, set the second as `background-color`

```
section {
border: 1px solid black;
background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found Your issue ..

1. Please create a div tag with class **navbar navbar-default**
2. add **a** tag inside **li** tag..

   ```
      <nav>
           <div class="navbar navbar-default">
           <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
           <li><a href="blog.php">Blog</a></li>
           <li><a href="photography.php">Photography</a></li>
           </div>
       </nav>
   ```

And then Your CSS Code should be..

```
.navbar-default{
border:1px solid black !important;
background-color:whitesmoke !impartant;
}

 .navbar-default li a:hover{
  color:black !impartant;
 }
```

Please make sure this css code is placed after Bootstrap cdn link .

Please See the Live Preview  https://jsfiddle.net/w19fv5ds/

Thanks Good Luck..